# T-SQL Add text on first row of query

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssrs-2012

I have a table tag with 2 fields ID, Text. I'd like to make a query with distinct value of Text and add 'All' On first position (it's used in a SSRS parameter value)
I made the following query:

```
SELECT 'All' [Text] Union
Select DISTINCT [text] from tag
```

the problem is there are some text starting with number and came before the All Text in the query. How can I make the query in order to get All in the first Row

Comment: Sample data would be helpful

Comment: Let say there are Rows like the following:
1, 1w
2, SS
3, TT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 'All' AS [Text], 0 AS Sorter
UNION
SELECT [text], 1 AS Sorter
FROM tag
ORDER BY 2,1
```

If you just want the text, try:

```
WITH alltext AS (
SELECT 'All' AS [Text], 0 AS Sorter
UNION
SELECT [text], 1 AS Sorter
FROM tag
)
SELECT text FROM alltext ORDER BY sorter, text
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i removed `distinct` which isn't necessary when using `union`. also the `order by` in the first query had to be `order by 2,1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` to prevent ordering:

```
SELECT 'All' [Text] UNION ALL
(Select DISTINCT [text] from tag order by [text])
```

Comment: I don't see why ALL would fix this problem. I'd like to have 'All' In the first Row, but in the table I have some value like 1, 2 etc,and the query is ordering by value and they're coming before the 'All' Value.

Comment: amended my answer